# Convert dict to list of keys?

Tags: python

Is there a way in Python to generate a list of keys in a dict? For example:

```
>>>someDict = {'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3}
>>>someList = someDict.keys()
>>>print someList
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question. . .

Comment: I'm assuming that code would be runnable...?

Comment: Take out the example and put it as the answer

Comment: Are you talking about python 2 or 3?

Comment: This is why I love Python.

Comment: Why did you not run this code? Or look through the documentation? Seriously, posting this question will have taken you more time. *Try* stuff for yourself.

Comment: @Lattyware I was under the impression that if there isn't a(n) SO question about it, it's a good idea to ask it.

Comment: @tkbx Not for anything so insanely trivial. If it can be answered by scanning the documentation quickly, it's really not a good question, as that information is already easily available in a good format.

Comment: @Lattyware does the same apply to self-answers?

Comment: I'm no authority on the matter, but yes. I'd say so - no value is added to anyone by having trivial questions on SO. It's pointless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>>someDict = {'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3}
>>>someList = list(someDict.keys())
>>>print(someList)
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Comment: `keys` method of `dict` returns `list`, so you don't need to convert it.

Comment: @alexvassel depends on the version of Python

Comment: @alexvassel python3 return view object

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x `dict.keys()` will do it, but in 3.x you have to use `list(dict.keys())` as it's a `dict_keys` object instead... (ie, it's not a `list`)

Of course, just writing `mylist = list(dict)` works on both though, since `list` takes an iterable, and the iterable of a dict is its keys...

You'll have to (somehow) force them into order if you expect keys to be in the same order you initialised the `dict` with, or look at [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)